# Return only the first word from a sentence and all other unique words from text file?

Tags: python, text

Say I have a text file *"list.txt"* which looks like this:

```
Supplychain/dealer/etc.
Supplychain/parts/etc.
Supplychain/shop/etc.
Supplychain/order/etc.
Supplychain/tasks/etc.
Supplychain/payment/etc.
Workshop/location/etc.
Workshop/name/etc.
Workshop/report/etc.
Customer/info/etc.
Customer/order/etc.
```

How can I get return only the first word without duplication, they shall be unique?

I have tried to solve like this and have tried other methods too, but I only get the full list of duplication and whole path.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlOsl.png)

I expect output to be:

```
Supplychain
Workshop
Customer
```

Comment: copy the code in the post pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A one line method of doing this is:

```
textfile = open("list.txt")
words = set(i.strip().split('/')[0] for i in textfile.readlines())
```

This will give you a list of the first words with no duplicates.

Comment: Thank you. this works! 
But how do you sort this? I thought it might be sorted automatic...

Comment: Hi, I'm glad this helped. What do you mean by sort them?

Answer (score 0):

My approach:

```
# Step 1 - extract the first words

file_content = """Supplychain/dealer/etc.
Supplychain/parts/etc.
Supplychain/shop/etc.
Supplychain/order/etc.
Supplychain/tasks/etc.
Supplychain/payment/etc.
Workshop/location/etc.
Workshop/name/etc.
Workshop/report/etc.
Customer/info/etc.
Customer/order/etc."""

words = file_content.split('\n') # Splitting by new line
first_parts = [word.split('/')[0] for word in words] # Get the part of the string that is before the '/'

# Step 2 - Get the unique parts
unique_first_parts = set(first_parts)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do :

```
result = []
with open("RestRout3.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        # Traiter la ligne et ainsi de suite ...

        first_word = line.split('/')[0]
        print(first_word)
        if not(first_word in result):
            result.append(first_word)

print(result)
```